# How to assign only the value that are true inside a tuple to a variable

Tags: python, tuples

For example `a = (3, False, False, False)`
or a = `(False, 4, False, False)`

How can I assign the only true value of the tuple to a variable, in python?

I don't care about the position and there won't ever be 2 values that are true, so

For example if

```
a = (3, False, False, False),
```

I want b = 3 (the only true value of a)
or if

```
a = (False, 4, False, False)
```

I want b = 4

EDIT:

I could do:

```
for value in a:
    if value:
        print value
```

but is there a less complicated way for such a simple problem?

Comment: What should happen if there is more than one non-false value in the tuple?

Comment: it wont happen but if it were, it would just take the first true value because  both true value would be equal anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [i for i in a if i is not False][0]
```

Comment: thanks it work and is pythonic!! as a newbie in that way of writting I am wondering what is the [0] for and what it does, could you explain?

Comment: @Tissuebox It is an index into the list created by the list comprehension. Since there is only one "truthy" element, the first index in the list will be it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with `None` as the function element:

```
>>> a=filter(None,(3, False, False, False))
```

Or just actually use a loop with with `break` and the last value of the loop element is what you seek:

```
>>> for e in (3, False, False, False):
...    if e: break
... 
>>> e
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `next` and a generator expression.

```
next(x in a if x)
```